# bootstrap3.02: table-responsive doesn't work in mobile phone, but works in firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

bootstrap3.02: table-responsive doesn't work  in mobile phone, but works in firefox. 
the code is as follows:

```
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="table12" class="table" >
            <tr><td>my god </td><td>my god </td><td>my god </td><td>my god </td><td>my god </td><td>my god </td></tr>
            <tr><td>my god </td><td>my god </td><td>my god </td><td>my god </td><td>my god </td><td>my god </td></tr>
        </table>     
    </div>
```

If the  firefox browser window in pc computer is small enough,  scroll bar will appear at the bottom of the table. But if the uc browser window in mobile phone is small enough,  scroll bar will not appear at the bottom of the table. and in 360 browser in mobile phone , i can scroll the table by moving my finger, but the scroll bar still doesn't appear. why? thanks!

Comment: it's browser's compatibility. scroll bar will appear in chrome browser in mobile phone. my god.

Answer (score 0):

you can use your owne mediaQuery from your html page to overide ".table-responsive" class
`<style>
 @media (max-width:'**strong text**yourmaxpixel'px)
        {
.table-responsive
            {
                width: 100%;
                margin-bottom: 15px;
                overflow-x: scroll;
                overflow-y: hidden;
                border: 1px solid #ddd;
                -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
                -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
            }
}
</style>`